# Find the center and the radius of convergence, complex numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am very lost and do not know how to do any of these even though I know how to do them for regular numbers. Can someone help?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^n(z+1)^n$$

Can I use the Cauchy–Hadamard formula? $\lim_{n \to \infty} \left | \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right | = Radius$

So since $a = 4^n$ then

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{4^n}{4^{n+1}}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{4^n}{4^{n} * 4}) = \frac{1}{4}$$

So that's the radius correct? What's the center?

Next questions:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{-1^n}{(2n)!}(z-\frac{1}{2}\pi)^{2n}$$

and:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n(n-1)}{3^n}(z-i)^{2n}$$

Comment: Yes the first radius is $1/4$. The first series is about $-1$ due to the $(z + 1)$ form.

Comment: What about the next two @0XLR